# compare and remove duplicates from mysql db

Tags: php, mysql

Example table (cart):

```
itemid | userid        | amount
------ | ------------- | -------
2      | 8.8.4.4       | 9
2      | usr@gmail.com | 3
```

Example: IP: 8.8.4.4 belongs to usr@gmail.com, the user added some items to his cart without account. once he logged in he noticed his previous cart items from an earlier session are still there but now he sees the same item twice in his cart.

How can I upon login combine these two rows into one row with the amount value updated to (in this case) 12 and userid updated to usr@gmail.com. The itemid should stay the same.

Currently I do the following which I try to replace with the above example:

```
$getIPdata = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE userid = '$IP'";

$IPcartdata = $mysqli->query($getIPdata);

if ($IPcartdata->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $IPcartdata->fetch_assoc()) {

mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE cart SET userid = '$login_session' WHERE userid = '$IP'");
   }
}
```

I have no idea where to start on doing this.

Thanks

Comment: Does your code not work? What happens when you run that code? Also, why are you using `$mysqli->query(...)` to select, but `mysqli_query($mysqli,...)` to update?

Comment: @Sean thanks for replying, the code I pasted was just an example of what i'm doing now, I am trying to replace that with a better solution. Which I have no idea on how to do (see my explanation example)

Comment: IPs aren't people and shouldn't be associated as such. If you had two users on the same network their carts would collide.

Comment: @chris85 I have thought about that but the likelihood of that happening are (in my case very slim) but thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with three queries without having to fetch any data:

```
UPDATE cart SET userid = '8.8.4.4' WHERE userid = 'usr@gmail.com';
INSERT INTO cart (itemid, userid, amount)
    SELECT itemid, 'usr@gmail.com', SUM(amount) FROM cart
     WHERE userid = '8.8.4.4' GROUP BY itemid;
DELETE FROM cart WHERE userid = '8.8.4.4';
```

You should use InnoDB tables and wrap those queries in a single transaction to make sure that either all or none of the queries are executed.

It might look a bit surprising that the first UPDATE sets the userid to the IP address instead of the username. This is done to essentially use the cart associated with the IP address as some kind of temporary storage to keep all entries from both carts before summing them up into the final cart.

If your table has a UNIQUE or PRIMARY key covering *both* itemid and userid (`ALTER TABLE cart ADD UNIQUE itemid_userid_idx (itemid, userid);`), this doesn't work (the initial UPDATE may create conflicts), however in this case you can do it instead in just two queries:

```
REPLACE INTO cart (itemid, userid, amount)
    SELECT itemid, 'usr@gmail.com', SUM(amount) FROM cart
     WHERE userid = '8.8.4.4' OR userid = 'usr@gmail.com'
     GROUP BY itemid;
DELETE FROM cart WHERE userid = '8.8.4.4';
```

But keep in mind that this absolutely requires the UNIQUE index I mentioned, since this is needed by the REPLACE to recognize duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

How about this? Need three steps.

```
select sum(amount) from cart where userid = '$IP' // fetch the result and save it in, say, $sum

update cart set amount = amount + $sum where userid = '$login_session'

delete from cart where userid='$IP'
```

Comment: You may want to change the sub query to `select sum(amount) from cart where userid = '$IP' GROUP BY userid` in case there are multiple duplicate rows.

Comment: @shiping that does not seem to be working for me, isn't the itemid part relevant or can we ignore that in this case? also, this might be a stupid question but are those two separate queries or one?

Comment: @Sean you mean use group by and sum between the brackets in the query of sean? Thanks for your help I really appreciate it!

Comment: @shiping yes, the query between the brackets. But you also need to address the `itemid` condition that the OP needs as well.

Comment: @Sean i agree with you. i did think about it and then thought if same IP could create more rows, the ower (who knows how the system was implemented) could just make the changes.

Comment: according to what the owner said, seems he/she just wanted to combine the rows (adding 3 and 9 to get 12). if itemid should be kept distinct, then it has to be used in the where clauses.

Comment: I am a little bit confused... I am currently trying this `mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE cart SET amount = amount + (SELECT amount FROM cart WHERE userid = '$IP') WHERE userid = '$login_session' DELETE FROM cart WHERE userid= '$IP' ");` which isn't working for me.

Comment: @Niels you have to do it in two steps. first update, then delete. not sure if it'd work, but you could try adding a semicolon (;) before the word delete.

Comment: okay I did that but it just deletes the rows with the IP it does not update the row with the username. thanks for your patients.

PS: im going to sleep now cause it's 5am here and i've been at it for way to long now haha. I will reply tomorrow, thanks for the help so far!

Comment: @Niels here i assumed (from what's shown in your query) $login_session contained the user's email address (here usr@gmail.com in this example). if it's not the case, then it wouldn't work.

Comment: if the user is not logged in then  `$login_session = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` if the user IS logged then  `$login_session = $_SESSION['login_user'];` and `$IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` is always set.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134332/discussion-between-shiping-and-niels).

Comment: I'm surprised nobody noticed that this falls on its face as soon as one of the carts contains more than just one item with another itemid (or if both carts just contain different items).

Comment: @aferber it depends on the actual purpose. the online shopping cart shows only how many items you have, not what they are. the owner just wanted to merge the rows created under different situations, so here is about how to do that. whether or not that makes sense is a different issue and is up to the owner of post to decide or find out. as a matter of fact there's a brief discussion about itemid in comments.